# Permanant shortcut to paste custom text

Tags: shortcuts, paste

I am looking for a way to create a permanent keyboard short cut to paste a text.
Example: Whenever I press strg+shift+F1 I would like to paste "Quod erat demonstrandum."
Maybe there is way to do this with the default Ubuntu settings or CompizConfig?